# How should Go Context be declared?

Tags: mongodb, go

Suppose I have a file that modifies database, should the functions share a single context or should each function have their own context?

Sharing context

```
var (
    ctx = context.Background()
)

func test1() {
    res, err := Collection.InsertOne(ctx, data)
}

func test2() {
    res, err := Collection.InsertOne(ctx, data)
}
```

Or should it be like this?

```
   func test1() {
        res, err := Collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), data)
    }
    
    func test2() {
        res, err := Collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), data)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the first approach. Context is something to be passed down to functions, it should not be declared as a global variable.

The second approach can be used at times, especially if there is no request context. However, if multiple calls are handled within a single server context, you should pass down the context for that call to all the other calls getting a context, so when the context is canceled or expired, all calls would fail.

Comment: *"it should not be declared as a shared variable"* -> what exactly do you mean? Also, it's perfectly fine to pass a context around — you can pass it to multiple functions and multiple goroutines, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Changed that to "..global variable" instead of shared variable.

Answer (score 8):

Neither. Your context should be request-scoped (for whatever "request" means in your application) and passed down the call chain to each function.

```golang
func test1(ctx context.Context) {
    res, err := Collection.InsertOne(ctx, data)
}

func test2(ctx context.Context) {
    res, err := Collection.InsertOne(ctx, data)
}
```

If you're building a web server, as indicated in comments, you'll usually get your context from the HTTP request in your handler:

```golang
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    // now pass ctx to any fuction that needs it. This way, if the HTTP
    // client/browser cancels the request, your downstream functions will
    // be able to abort immediately, without wasting time finishing their
    // work.
}
```

Comment: Using your approach, my ctx would be initialized once in main.go's main function. So you are saying that all my database modification functions should use the same ctx that was declared in the main?

Comment: I don't know. That depends on what your app is doing. If your program starts, does some queries, then exits, then yes, a single `ctx` in main makes sense. If it's a web server, for instance, you should use one `ctx` per HTTP request.

Comment: Oh okay yeah mine is a webserver. That clarifies it, thank you